# Error accessing FTPS site from unix - "curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <ftp site>"

Tags: curl, ftps, filezilla

I'm using filezilla ftp server on windows server 2008 machine. I have setup the FTPS site on this server. It works fine when i create any fpts account and access it from any ftp windows client. But when i try to access this FTPS site from Unix machine it prompt me error -
 "curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to " on the client side."

I checked the log on the server and it says connection disconnected.
**Server Log:**
150 Connection accepted
226 Transfer OK
disconnected.

can anybody suggest me solution for this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some versions of OpenSSL have been reported to have problems connecting to some SSL servers. Try upgrading OpenSSL on the Unix machine if you can, or force an SSL 3.0 connection with curl's -3 option. This assumes that you're not trying to make an implicit ftps connection to the server's unencrypted port. That would cause an SSL handshake when the server isn't expecting it, and could cause an SSL error like you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Dan, yes i added -3 option and added couple other options and it worked!